# What are two similar words, one meaning to create illusions, or the process of creating illusions, and one meaning to transform into a beam of light?

Tags: names, dynamic-verbs

I need two words, that preferably rhyme (but similar sounding words are okay) that mean (they don't have to in common usage, but just have to be able to be repurposed to mean) the process of creating illusions, false images, hallucinations, etc. and the process of turning into a beam of light, (ditto)

Comment: Can you use _illustrate_ and _illuminate_? Or dream up and stream down?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: *Hallucinate* and *irridiate* rhyme with you proposals.

Comment: How about daze and lase

Comment: How many words do you think there are that mean "transform into a beam of light"?  How many can you name?

Comment: I like Yosef's, you should have put that as an answer

Comment: @YosefBaskin That would be a good answer, and I'd probably give you the point for it.

Comment: For questions asking for writing advice, I suggest you try the Writers.SE chat room. Writing advice is not on topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you use illustrate and illuminate? Or dream up and stream down?